# Controller not working properly in CodeIgniter app

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to run the function `add_supplier` of the controller purchase

The function in the controller is:

```
public function add_supplier($id = null)
{
    $this->tbl_supplier('supplier_id');
    if ($id) { //condition check
        $result = $this->global_model->get_by(array('supplier_id' => $id), true);
        if ($result) {
            $data['supplier'] = $result;
        } else {
            //msg
            $type = 'error';
            $message = 'Sorry, No Record Found!';
            set_message($type, $message);
            redirect('admin/purchase/manage_supplier');
        }
    }

    // view page
    $data['title'] = 'Add New Supplier';
    $data['editor'] = $this->data;
    $data['subview'] = $this->load->view('admin/purchase/add_supplier', $data, true);
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
}
```

I am trying to call this function using:

`<li> <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/purchase/add_supplier">Add Supplier</a></li>`

The redirect link is fine. I have run other controller function successfully by using the same method, but in this case when I click on this anchor tag, I should be redirected to `add_supplier` page, but instead I'm redirected to the dashboard page. Its location is `admin/dashboard`.

I cannot find the reason behind this behavior. I am not using any session redirect in `add_Supplier` view.

Comment: is purchase ur controller

Comment: yes. purchase is controller

Comment: and dashboard method is in purchase controller

Comment: no. add_supplier is in controller purchase

Comment: show ur routes.php

Comment: <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = "login";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: and admin is ur directory folder? u have to create route for ur admin

Comment: i dont think that is an issue because i have another controller but it is working fine. the views for that controller are in admin folder too

Comment: is purchase controller  in admin folder in application directory

Comment: yes . it is under controllers/admin

Comment: i have another controller called customer also located in controllers/admin

.When i copied the function from purchase controller to customer controller and called that function through customer controller the page has loaded correctly.

So i think the purchase controller has some issue.

Can you tell me what might be causing this?

Comment: make sure name of purchase class in purchase controller. may be copy paste error

Comment: the name looks fine. Wrong name causes 404 error